# Unpacking .z01 .z02 .z03 without .zip on LINUX

Tags: linux, zip, archiving, 7-zip

I have received several archives and they all have extensions of .z01 .z02 .z03 etc.

There is no .zip file and no .z00 file.

If I transfer these files to my Mac and run them through un-stuffit, it unpacks fine.
But I cannot work out who to do this on my NAS (Linux) via the terminal window
(I actually want to automate the process, so it needs to happen on the linux box)

I have tried zip -FF file.z01 --out newfile.zip 
and then unzip newel.zip  but that fails.
I have tried 7z  and all other suggested options (that relate to having a .zip file) fail.

Can someone point me in the right direction. Do I need a particular version of zip or 7z ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure these are all the archive files? Maybe you're missing a `.zip` or `.z00` file somewhere. Or try running `file` on the files (using `file *` in their directory works), they may not be zip files at all.

Could also try using `cat` to "paste" together all the files in the right order, and write to a file (if they're small) or pipe that straight into `zip`/`unzip`:

```
cat .z01 .z02 .z03 ... | unzip
```

Should be able to use wildcards for the filenames too, like `cat name.z*`, and testing the list/order with `echo name.z*` could help too/first.

But `man unzip` says it should be able to handle wildcards itself, so just this might work too:

```
unzip name.z*
```

Possibly requiring escaping (`name.z\*`) or quoting the asterisk `unzip "name.z*"` See `man unzip`.

If the above don't work, then from the `man unzip` bug (listed below), you may have to `cat` all the files into a single file, and then run `zip -F` or `zip -FF`, as in:

`zip -F foo --out foofix` or `zip -FF foo --out foofixfix`

And then unzipping `foofix` or `foofixfix`

---

Info from `man unzip`:

> BUGS
>         Multi-part archives are not yet supported, except in  conjunction  with
>          zip.  (All parts must be concatenated together in order, and then ``zip
>          -F'' (for zip 2.x) or ''zip -FF'' (for zip 3.x) must  be  performed  on
>          the  concatenated  archive  in  order to ''fix'' it.  Also, zip 3.0 and
>          later can combine multi-part (split) archives into a  combined  single-
>          file  archive using ''zip -s- inarchive -O outarchive''.  See the zip 3
>          manual page for more information.)  This will definitely  be  corrected
>          in the next major release.

And this info from `man zip` may be useful:

> **Split archives**.  zip version 3.0 and later can create  split  archives.
>          A  split  archive  is a standard zip archive split over multiple files.
>          (Note that split archives are not just archives split in to pieces,  as
>          the  offsets of entries are now based on the start of each split.  Concatenating the pieces together will invalidate these offsets, but unzip
>          can  usually  deal  with it.  zip will usually refuse to process such a
>          spliced archive unless the -FF fix option is used to fix the offsets.)
>
> ...
>
> In addition, streamed archives, entries encrypted with standard encryption,  or  split archives created with the pause option may not be compatible with PKZIP as data descriptors are used and PKZIP at  the  time
>          of  this  writing does not support data descriptors (but recent changes
>          in the PKWare published zip standard now include some support  for  the
>          data descriptor format zip uses).

Comment: Definitely an archive - Unstuffit (on Mac) unpacks it fine.

Comment: Have tried using cat to create a .zip file - as you mention - Doesn't work.  Have tried zip, unzip, 7z no success. Only way  I can unpack is to transfer the files to my Mac and use UnStuffit.

Comment: Updated with `-F` & `-FF` options, wasn't quite done writing the answer yet

Comment: Yes, I have tried the -F and -FF options. It doesn't seem to do anything productive in my case.  I'll see if Unstuffy can shed some light on the type of archive.

Comment: On most linux (linuxii?) the `file` command often tells something useful, with `file *` for every file in a dir. And trying the gui `file-roller` archive manager (or another one) might work a little better too

Comment: Solved it.  Stupid file is a RAR archive. `unrar e filename.z01` worked a treat.  Problem solved!

Comment: `file file.z01` gave me: file file.z01
file.z01: RAR archive data, v1d, flags: Archive volume, os: Win32

Comment: A "comment solution" is a solution nontheless, I'll edit in the "check with `file` first" to my answer, in the "are you sure it's not missing someting" part, should at least get an upvote (hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Stupid file is a RAR archive. `unrar e filename.z01` worked a treat. Problem solved